# PHP MYSQL ORDER BY DESC then ASC

Tags: php

I have got this MYSQL

```
SELECT * FROM chat WHERE To_='$NameId' OR From_='$NameId' ORDER BY `DATE` DESC LIMIT 0,50
```

This code returns me data in this order

`1 newest
 2 newest
 3 newest
 4 newest
 5 newest`

But i want data to be returned in this way

`5 newest
 4 newest
 3 newest
 2 newest
 1 newest`

How can i do that?

Comment: `ORDER BY \`DATE\` ASC`?

Comment: @u_mulder it returns the oldest ones

Comment: just `array_reverse` your output in PHP?

Comment: please clarify which column you want to order .. from which columns came the digits 1-5?

Comment: *"ORDER BY DESC then ASC"* - what did you mean by that in your title? Your question's short on detail. What @u_mulder suggested should work as per what you posted for code.

Comment: as i understood you need 50 records and from 50 to 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this :

```
SELECT * FROM (select * from chat where To_='$NameId' OR From_='$NameId' ORDER BY DATE DESC LIMIT 0,50) sub ORDER BY DATE ASC
```

Comment: Why should OP use this? Please clarify your answer a bit.

Comment: he is creating a chat app, he need get data in desc order and display in asc in chat page

Comment: how about performace of this aproach?

Comment: @Pepo_rasta since result of sub query is limited to 50 records, it will not result in any poor performance. (even if you use this nested query, in other query)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to change direction of records **after** getting first 50 records.

You can use sub-query feature of MySQL. Assume that result of your query is new, shiny table. So write SQL for desired result using this *table* (actually it is data set). (In our case we rename it as ***results***)

```
SELECT * FROM (select * from chat where To_='$NameId' OR From_='$NameId' ORDER BY DATE DESC LIMIT 0,50) as results ORDER BY results.DATE ASC
```

Also if you have "count" of results you can do same thing using single-level query. Think about that;

```
SELECT * FROM chat WHERE To_='$NameId' OR From_='$NameId' ORDER BY `DATE` ASC LIMIT ***MyCount***,50
```

> MySQL will not force you to rename your sub-query results but renaming
>   them results in more readable SQL codes.